# Authy not giving any options for country code

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I had 2 factor auth working with Google authenticator and Authy. For some reason, Authy stopped giving me options in the dropdown for country code, and I can't get it working.

Any idea how to fix this? I don't see any console errors.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out the reason for this issue?

Comment: No. I haven't looked at it for a few months now. I reached out to Authy and they couldn't help me

Comment: So I did some more digging and chances are you your table isn't populated. The table is tfa_country_codes. There is a patch file that needs to be ran. To re run it simple delete the Patch out of the patch_list table and run set up. Hope that is helpful